# Parse.com Push REST Api query own column

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi there I want to integrate parse.com push to my existing Android App.
at parse.com I added two new coloumn "nick" and "userid" to the Installation Table and at my php Push I want to send a push to one specific user/userId.
This is my array, but all the time I get a {"code":1,"error":"internal error"} response.

```
$data = array(
            'type' => 'android',
            'where' => array(
                    'nick' => "Andy",
            ),
            'channel' => '',
            'data' => array(
                    'alert' => $message,
            ),
    );
```

"Andy" does exist in the Table/Database and the coloumn is named right.
Has anybody a hint for me how to query for that coloumns?

Thanks for Reading
Greets Soma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok now found the answer I had this one in the array:
        'type' => 'android',
        'channel' => '',

Putting this to the 'where' array did the trick.

```
     $data = array(

            'where' => array(
                    'nick' => "Andy",
                    'type' => 'android',
                    'channel' => '',
            ),

            'data' => array(
                    'alert' => $message,
            ),
    );
```

Thanks